# recover data using a laptop running Ubuntu, but won't load

Tags: data-recovery

How can I recover data on a laptop that is running Ubuntu, if Ubuntu doesn't load?

Answer (score 0):

You can boot with Ubuntu LiveUSB and copy your data anywhere you like.